# Compare LinkedList by multiple strings in Java

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have a custom object like this :

```
 Linkedlist<ClassInfo> classes = new LinkedList<ClassInfo>();
```

Within that, there are accessors for a teacher's name, the class name, the room number, etc. These are all Strings. I have run into a situation where the data in that LinkedList needs to displayed by different parameters (i.e. teacher name, class name, the room number, etc.).

Can anyone supply a quick implementation of how to do this? If I use the Compartor interface, **how would I be able tell it which String field to sort the list by?** My research also lead me to the Collator, and I was wondering if this would be of use.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a different `Comparator` implementation for each field:

```
Comparator<ClassInfo> CLASS_NAME_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<ClassInfo>() {
  public int compare(ClassInfo class1, ClassInfo class2) {
    return class1.getClassName().compareTo(class2.getClassName());
  }
};
... // implementations for other fields
```

...and then sort by whichever comparator is appropriate:

```
Collections.sort(classes, CLASS_NAME_COMPARATOR);
```

Comment: This is great, really appreciate it! We just touched on the Comparator the other day, so I knew I was on the right track - just wasn't sure how to make it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to provide a custom comparator for every ordering you need to sort your collection to. Eg:

```
class TeacherComparator implements Comparator<ClassInfo> {
  public int compare(ClassInfo c1, ClassInfo c2) {
    String teacher1 = c1.getTeacher();
    String teacher2 = c2.getTeacher();
    return teacher1.compareTo(teacher2);
  }
}

class ClassNameComparator implements Comparator<ClassInfo> {
  ...
}
```